# Ambiguous Sub Name with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ambiguous

What's wrong with this sub name which gives me an ambiguous name detected error?

```
Public Property Get G_EtoW_Pad()
    G_EtoW_Pad = EtoW_Pad
End Property
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because G_EtoW_Pad is already declared elsewhere

Comment: You should never skip your morning coffee.